# How to make image one side stable using jqueryrotate

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an image one side is should be stable and only one side should be rotate.That image is like a pole.bottom side i should not move the position only top side i want to rotate to 90.i tried like this.I am using jqueryrotate plugin.how can i get it?

```
<script>
  $(".pole").rotate({
     angle:0,
     animateTo:90,
     duration:4000,
  });

</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to transform rectangle image to arrow shape?

Comment: one pole image is there i want to rotate clock wise.bottom of the image position should not be change,only top of the image should be rotate.it's like second's hand in clock.